# Undefined при GET запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js

Имеется вот такой "локальный ад из callback'ов"
Сделано на Node.JS, помогите исправить

```
function getResponse(_url) {
    http.get(_url, function(res) {
        return res;
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        log("AUTH ERROR! Reason: "+e);
    });
}
function checkAuth(login, password) {
    var response = getResponse("somehost.ru", "/updater/auth.php?login="+login+"&pass="+password);

    if(response == "Success") {
        return [true, login, "user", ""];
    } else {
        return [false, login, "user", response];
    }
}
//часть из кода авторизации
case "auth":
    localUserInfo = checkAuth(cmdArr[1], cmdArr[2]);
        if(localUserInfo[0]) {
            userAuthed = localUserInfo[0];
            userName = localUserInfo[1];
            userGroup = localUserInfo[2];
            connection.send("succauth "+userName);
            log("User with ID: "+index+" successfully logged in! Login: "+userName);
            } else {
                log("User with ID: "+index+" failed to auth properly. Disconnecting..");
                connection.send("err autherr");
                connection.send("err "+localUserInfo[3]);
                connection.close();
            }
```

Выхлоп с консоли клиента:

> localjs.js:34 Error: autherr
>   localjs.js:34 Error: undefined
>   localjs.js:40 Server closed connection..

undefined тут это:

```
localUserInfo[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback - это когда вы передаете в функцию в качестве аргумента другую функцию, (собственно callback), которая будет вызвана когда та функция завершит работу. Код тем временем выполняется дальше. В вашем коде ни  одного callbackа нет (вернее есть один - анонимная функция в http.get). Из-за их отсутствия ничего не работает. http.get - асинхронная функция, там return не работает так, как вы себе это представляете. Вместо него вы должны как раз вызывать callback и передавать ему response в качестве аргумента.

Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

```
function getResponse(_url, callback) {
    http.get(_url, function(res) {
        callback(res);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        log("AUTH ERROR! Reason: "+e);
    });
}
function checkAuth(login, password, callback) {
    getResponse("somehost.ru/updater/auth.php?login="+login+"&pass="+password,function(response){
        if(response == "Success") {
            callback([true, login, "user", ""]);
        } else {
            callback([false, login, "user", response]);
        }
    });
}

//часть из кода авторизации
case "auth":
    checkAuth(cmdArr[1], cmdArr[2],function(localUserInfo){
        if(localUserInfo[0]) {
            .........
        } else {
            .........
        }
    });
```

Comment: Я люблю тебя, Darth, спасибо за помощь!